# Google chrome same url cache

Tags: caching, google-chrome

I'm testing my servlet using google chrome. When i tried to load the same url twice, say,

**localhost/myserver/servlet**

chrome only sent out one request to the server. However, if I modified the second url to be:

**localhost/myserver/servlet?id=2**

it sent two different requests.
I've enabled the incognito mode, but it seems that chrome shares cache and urls between all its incognito tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Caching control is a part of HTTP specification, read something about it. Using HTTP headers like `Cache-Control: no-cache` or `Expires: ...` should help you.